# Java: Two Scanners reading from the same input file. Doable? Useful?

Tags: java, string, io, integer, java.util.scanner

I have to read in integers from an input file based on whether or not a string that appears before them is a certain keyword "load". There is no key number telling how many numbers are about to be inputted. These numbers must be saved to an array. In order to avoid creating and updating a new array for each additional number scanned, I'd like to use a second scanner to first find the amount of integers, and then have the first scanner scan that many times before reverting back to testing for strings. My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File fileName = new File("heapops.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
    Scanner loadScan = new Scanner(fileName);
    String nextInput;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        nextInput = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(nextInput);
        if(nextInput.equals("load"))
        {
            loadScan = scanner;

            nextInput = loadScan.next();
            while(isInteger(nextInput)){
                i++;
                nextInput = loadScan.next();
            }

            int heap[] = new int[i];
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
                nextInput = scanner.next();
                System.out.println(nextInput);
                heap[j] = Integer.parseInt(nextInput);
                System.out.print(" " + heap[j]);
            }
        }




    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

My problem seems to be that scanning via loadscan, the secondary scanner only meant for integers, also moves the primary scanner forward. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Any way to make the compiler treat scanner and loadscan as separate objects despite them preforming the same task?

Comment: Are all the numbers on one line? If so, then I would use a Scanner for the File and Scanners for each line that requires it. But remembering to dispose of all Scanners when no longer needed.

Comment: Note, in your code above, you're creating two Scanner objects, but are using only one of them since you call `loadScan = scanner;` which assigns the same Scanner object to both Scanner variables.

Comment: Also, why not save your numbers to an `ArrayList<Integer>` and not an array? Then you don't have to worry so much about declaring the correct size of the array.

Comment: Hovercraft, do you know of any way to make the two scanners point at the same area of the file without becoming the same object?

Comment: Please answer my questions first. Let's not make an XY Problem out of this. Also please show a typical text file that you'd read, or perhaps a small version of one.

Answer (score 2):

You may certainly have two Scanner objects read from the same File object simultaneously. Advancing one will not advance the other.

**Example**

Assume that the contents of `myFile` are `123 abc`. The snippet below

```
    File file = new File("myFile");
    Scanner strFin = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner numFin = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println(numFin.nextInt());
    System.out.println(strFin.next());
```

... prints the following output...

```
123
123
```

However, I don't know why you would want to do that. It would be much simpler to use a single Scanner for your purposes. I called mine `fin` in the following snippet.

```
String next;
ArrayList<Integer> readIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
while (fin.hasNext()) {
    next = fin.next();
    while (next.equals("load") {
        next = fin.next();
        while (isInteger(next)) {
            readIntegers.Add(Integer.parseInt(next));
            next = fin.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the last while loop should be a while loop in your example code? next is never edited in the body so it either loops for infinity or not at all

Comment: @ferrybig That should probably be an `if`. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @ferrybig Whoops, no, I made it worse. After the "load" keyword there can be any number of numbers. I think the `while` was supposed to be there, but I forgot to advance the scanner each time. It's been over a year since I saw this question, so bear with me.